# Mujoco in Ubuntu error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mujoco

I was trying to install Mujoco in Ubuntu. I have downloaded mujoco200, and put it to ./mujoco with the license. Then downloaded mujoco_py with 'pip3 install mujoco_py==2.0.2.8'. According to the instructions I read online that should be all, and then when I run 'import mujoco_py', the following error shows:

distutils.errors.CompileError: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? If not, I am using Mac M1, does anyone know how else can I use Mujoco since I don't think I can use Mujoco in Mac M1?

At first, the terminal asks me to put 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/yilin/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin' in .bashrc, I did that and that bug is gone. But now this bug comes up. I have tried to use Mujoco with Mac, use mujoco_py in colab and both of them failed.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you want to use mujoco 2.0.0 rather than a later version of MuJoCo? mujoco_py supports the free MuJoCo since November last year (install mujoco_py==2.1.12.14).

Or better, avoid `mujoco_py`, and use the `mujoco` package on `pip` instead. If you're using Gym, read their note about the latest MuJoCo environments: https://github.com/openai/gym#mujoco-environments

Using `mujoco` rather than `mujoco_py` will avoid all installation problems, because the MuJoCo binary is included in that Python package and doesn't need to be installed separately. It works fine on Mac M1.